# Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'RSSParser'

Tags: flutter, widget, statefulwidget

I wanted to implements a simple tutorial of how parsing an Rss Feed with Flutter, here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webfeed/webfeed.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

 class RSSParser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    _RSSParserState createState() => _RSSParserState();
 }

 class _RSSParserState extends State<RSSParser> {
  final String url = "https://www.90min.com/posts.rss";
  RssFeed _feed;
  String _title;
  static const String loadingFeedMsg = 'Loading Feed...';
  static const String feedLoadErrorMsg = 'Error Loading Feed.';
  static const String feedOpenErrorMsg = 'Error Opening Feed.';

   Future<RssFeed> loadFeed() async{
    try{
    final client = http.Client();
    final response = await client.get(url);
     return RssFeed.parse(response.body);

  }
    catch(e){

   }
   return null;

 }

updateTitle(title){
  setState(() {
  _title = title;
});
}

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
updateTitle(widget.title);
}


updateFeed(feed){
 setState(() {
  _feed = feed;
 });
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_title),
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

The problem is that i got a compilation error in that instruction

```
 updateTitle(widget.title);
```

with the following error message:

> The getter 'title' isn't defined for the type 'RSSParser'

In the tutorial, it works fine!!

Do you have an idea how to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: This is not working as there is not title in `RSSParser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `title` for you RSS widget. It should look something like ths:

```
 class RSSParser extends StatefulWidget {
final String title;
const RSSParser({required this.title});
```

This should solve your error.

Comment: Yes! you are right! thats fixed my problem! I forgot the title variable in my RSSParser class.. thank you

Comment: You are most welcome! :) Please consider marking this as the answer to your question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because there is not title in RSS class.

I think you are not clear with use of `widget.something`. It means that in the class which extends `StatefulWidget` there is a `something` parameter which i need to get in stateObject.

See the code to understand.

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  String someData = 'SomeData'; // Some data 

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}


//This is the state object
class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {

 // Now that if you need some data from the above class. You use use this widget.someData to get it here
  String getHere = widget.someData ; 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```